# Maven assembly plugin not excluding resources from archive

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have some properties and XML files in my src/main/resources directory of my maven project. I would like to exclude these files

When building the binary, none of these files are being excluded even though I have set them up that way. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

My pom.xml set up

```
 <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <descriptors>
        <descriptor>src/main/resources/assembly-plugin/assembly.xml</descriptor>
      </descriptors>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

**assembly.xml** set up

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
  <id>distribution</id>
  <formats>
    <format>jar</format>
  </formats>
   <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/common-conf</directory>
      <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>*.*</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/dotcom-conf</directory>
      <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>*.*</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/olb-conf</directory>
      <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>*.*</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

I am executing `mvn package assembly:single` command to do the same.

The error logs

```
[INFO] Skipping project-jar
[INFO] This project has been banned from the build due to previous failures.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 40.074s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Aug 23 13:30:25 PDT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 29M/45M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.4.1:single (make-assembly) on project project-jar: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive distribution: You must set at least one file. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
```

Comment: Can you exactly desribe which files / folders should be packaged via maven-assembly-plugin and which not?

Comment: I want to exclude all files in src/main/resources/olb-conf/, src/main/resources/common-conf, and src/main/resources/common-conf

Comment: If you want to exclude all those files why don't you put them into a different folder like `src/main/olb-conf` ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Legacy code about 5 years old. I can't change the package structure as it breaks a lot of thing. I did try.

Answer (score 0):

could you explain what's your ${basedir}? It's an property to filter by maven resource process? then, you have to know: it's useless to exclue files unser src, it's not relative to generated artifact, you should replace them with target/classes/your-package.

here is an reference, it might no work, but you can learn how to config the

```
    <assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
  <id>distribution</id>
  <formats>
    <format>jar</format>
  </formats>
   <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>target/classes/common-conf</directory>
      <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>*.*</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>target/classes/dotcom-conf</directory>
      <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>*.*</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>target/classes/olb-conf</directory>
      <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>*.*</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```